# D3: How to assign size, colour to items (collision-detection visualisation)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and have built the following visualisation based on the collision-detection visualisation example on the D3js.io website (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298).

I'd like to be able to specify the size and colour of each of the 10 balls in my graph but I don't understand how to do that. At the moment, the code is relying on randomly generated size and the balls are all black. Can someone please explain how I can make these changes?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to specify hex codes and a specific px-width for each of the 10 balls.

My code is pasted below, and is also on Codepen: http://codepen.io/msummers40/pen/LiBmr

Thank you, in advance, for your assistance.

Matt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 500,
    height = 400;

var nodes = d3.range(11).map(function() { return {radius: Math.random() * 33 + 4}; }),
    root = nodes[0],
    color = d3.scale.category20();

root.radius = 80;
root.fixed = true;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.05)
    .charge(function(d, i) { return i ? 0 : -2000; })
    .nodes(nodes)
    .size([width, height]);

force.start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes.slice(1))
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });


force.on("tick", function(e) {
  var q = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes),
      i = 0,
      n = nodes.length;

  while (++i < n) q.visit(collide(nodes[i]));

  svg.selectAll("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});

svg.on("mousemove", function() {
  var p1 = d3.mouse(this);
  root.px = p1[0];
  root.py = p1[1];
  force.resume();
});

function collide(node) {
  var r = node.radius + 1,
      nx1 = node.x - r,
      nx2 = node.x + r,
      ny1 = node.y - r,
      ny2 = node.y + r;
  return function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if (quad.point && (quad.point !== node)) {
      var x = node.x - quad.point.x,
          y = node.y - quad.point.y,
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = node.radius + quad.point.radius;
      if (l < r) {
        l = (l - r) / l * .5;
        node.x -= x *= l;
        node.y -= y *= l;
        quad.point.x += x;
        quad.point.y += y;
      }
    }
    return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
  };
}

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radius and fill colour for the circles are set in this code (specifically the last two lines):

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes.slice(1))
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i % 3); });
```

The radius comes directly from the data, where it is generated like this:

```
{radius: Math.random() * 33 + 4}
```

To set a specific radius per circle, change what is returned there. If you want to specify explicitly the radii, have some static data like this:

```
var nodes = [{radius: 1}, {radius: 2}, ...];
```

The same works for the fill colour. You could add another attribute to the data to specify the colour (it looks like you're trying to do this already):

```
var nodes = [{radius: 1, color: "red"}, {radius: 2, color: "blue"}, ...];
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful. Can you explain just a bit more about what you mean in your second section of code, about changing the 'code' {radius: Math.random() * 33 + 4} line? I've made the modifications you mentioned below but I'm not quite clear how I change from the randomly generated figures to the specified radii.

Comment: Well `Math.random() * 33 + 4` will return a random number. If you replace this by a fixed number, you can control directly the radius of the circles. No other changes to the code are needed.

Comment: Thanks. In your original explanation, you described how I could detail specific radii for the different balls. So in this case if I want to specify 10 distinctly shaped balls, I'm not quite clear how these two rows should read. 'code'   .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
and 'code' var nodes = [{radius: 1}, {radius: 2}, ...]; Thanks, again, for your help.

Comment: Do you want distinct **shapes** or distinct **radii**?

Comment: Then giving different numbers in the data should be enough.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying this earlier but having problems getting everything to work. In any case, I'll give it another try this evening. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Lars, I've tried adding the radii to the 'code' var nodes area but it's not quite working for me yet. Instead of the visualisation displaying a series of circles with distinct radii, it takes the first radii and applies that to all of the circles. I really appreciate all of your help so far but is there any chance you could take one more look at the code?: [link](http://codepen.io/msummers40/pen/LiBmr) I'm hoping that I can wind up with a visualisation that contains ten circles of different radii and colour. The colour is set but the radii isn't quite working yet. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're doing something completely different to the code I've posted when defining `nodes` -- it works fine if you do it the way I've posted! See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cJnwH You can also use `d3.range`, but then you need to do something with that value and return a single element: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gsrbL

Comment: Hi Lars - thanks very much for your help on this. I'm just starting to figure out D3 and I appreciate you taking the time to show me what's not working in the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it, but the style method is not ok. You should change to **attr('fill')**, and then use your color scale:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes.slice(1))
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.index);  });
```

And you can do exaclty the same for size or whatever

Comment: Thank you! Forgive my ignorance here but can you explain what you mean by a color scale? I don't understand how, exactly, to set one up and to have it be recognised in the code you've provided.

Comment: It's in your code:  color = d3.scale.category20(); this generates a function that return a color from a 20 elemnts scale